# Need support with mySQL PDO JOIN statements

Tags: mysql, select, join, pdo

I need an SELECT with JOIN but have at this moment no idea how to do this. I read already a few tutorials but it does not help me with my problem.

I have 2 tables in 2 databases:

```
DATABASE A

-> CONTENT
--> | PARTNERID | PAYSITE   |
--> | 1         | siteA.com |
--> | 2         | siteA.com |
--> | 3         | siteA.com |
--> | 3         | siteB.com |


DATABASE B

-> WMIDPP
--> | WMID | PARTNERID | PARTNERURL | PAYSITE   | ACTIVE
--> | 1    | 1         | AFFLINK 1  | siteA.com | 1
--> | 1    | 2         | AFFLINK 2  | siteA.com | 1
--> | 2    | 1         | AFFLINK 1  | siteA.com | 1
```

The above tables contains more fields, but with these fields I need to work with.

I know already the variables $WMID and $PAYSITE if I enter the website. When I enter the website, it should be show only the following data:

The complete data from table CONTENT and the field PARTNERURL from table WMIDPP when

```
CONTENT.PARTNERID = WMIDPP.PARTNERID

and

WMIDPP.WMID = $WMID

and 

WMIDPP.PAYISTE = $PAYSITE

but only if

WMIDPP.ACTIVE = 1
```

Can anybody help with my problem?

Thanks in advance

Torsten

EDIT:

Here a little bit more information about the databases and tables:

Table CONTENT is located in DATABASE A and table WMIDPP is located in DATABASE B.

I access to these databases like this:

```
$DB_HOST  = "localhost";
$DB_NAME1 = "database1";
$DB_NAME2 = "database2";
$DB_USER  = "username";
$DB_PASS  = "password";
$OPTION   = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8");
try {
  $dbAS = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . $DB_NAME1, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $OPTION);
  $dbEC = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . $DB_NAME2, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $OPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e) { exit("Verbindung fehlgeschlagen! " . $e->getMessage()); }
```

User has permissions to access to both databases.

I have 2 different databases, because there are 2 different projects. If it not work with these configuration, I can move the table(s) from DATABASE B to DATABASE A - but this should only the worst case option. I prefer a solution to merge the data of the tables in 2 different databases.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a 'database' and a 'table'?

Comment: Yes - why did you ask?

Comment: Removed the 'test queries' i put in. That is the code that should allow you to do what to want. It is just a normal 'two table' join but specifying which databases to get the tables from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use One PDO connection.

The signon details must allow access to both databases you want to access.

The full 'path' to any column is:

```
<database name> . <table name> . <column name>.
```

Here is tested code that joins tables from two separate databases.

Database 1) is called: 'testmysql'

Database 2) is called: 'rags1'

They are just databases i have setup here with similar structured tables on them.

Join two tables from separate databases

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Query testmysql and rags1
 */
$sqlTest = 'SELECT rags1.user.id as RagsRowId,
                   rags1.user.userid as RagsUserId,

                   testmysql.customer.id as TestRowId,
                   testmysql.customer.custid as TestCustId,
                   testmysql.customer.address as TestCustAddress

            FROM testmysql.customer
                 JOIN rags1.user
                    ON testmysql.customer.custid = rags1.user.userid
                   AND testmysql.customer.custid = :testCustId';

$stmt = $dbTest->prepare($sqlTest);
$stmt->bindValue(':testCustId', 'rfv123', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

$testResult = $stmt->fetchAll();
$stmt->closeCursor();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($testResult);
echo '<pre>';
```

Connection Details:

```
/**
 * Two databases :
 *   1) testmysql
 *   2) rags1
 *
 *   Use the 'database' name that you want to refer to in the queries.
 */

/**
 * must have access rights to both db's
 */
// db connection to TestMysql and Rags1
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql';
$username = 'rfv123';
$password = 'rfv123';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
);
$dbTest = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
$dbTest->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [RagsRowId] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [RagsUserId] => rfv123
            [1] => rfv123
            [TestRowId] => 3
            [2] => 3
            [TestCustId] => rfv123
            [3] => rfv123
            [TestCustAddress] => 123 Somewhere Street, Cheshire
            [4] => 123 Somewhere Street, Cheshire
        )

)
```

Comment: Wow ... a lot of code ;-)
I try to understand it and will play a little bit around with ...
Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is just a single separate query on each of the two separate databases to demonstrate that they can each be accessed from one connection. The final query is just a normal join of two tables but from separate databases. Only look at the last query to do what you want.

Comment: Note this assumes the databases are available on the same connection... but if they arent im not aware of a way to accomplish this.

Comment: @prodigitalson, you are correct as far as i can tell. A quick internet search revealed more 'issues' than 'answers'. ;-/ Which, in a way makes sense, as the query could be pulling rather a lot of data down to the 'local machine' before processing it. Not nice. I suspect 'selective' replication' from the remote db  on to the the local machine would need to be setup - carefully?

Comment: @RyanVincent
You connect here to 1 database (testmysql):
"$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testmysql';"

But I don't understand how the connection to the 2nd db works.

Comment: @C3X, As long as you have privileges 'access' to both databases then all will be fine. What databases you have access to is defined in your 'user settings' with 'mysql'. The 'dbname' in the PDO 'dsn' is just a 'suggestion' and not important. It sets the 'default database' is all. Think of it as doing a 'use database' after the connection to 'mysql' is made. When you use another 'database' name in your 'query' then your 'privileges' are checked and validated that you can access the other 'database'. It is all done by 'mysql' not PDO.

Comment: @C3X. In the queries i use - the 'database name' is always supplied so it is not important what the 'default database' is. I just want access to the 'explicit' tables and columns i asked for. There is not one shortcut i use in the queries for that reason. You can see the full path to every item of information that is accessed. I aliased them  as columns to make the output more readable.

Comment: @C3X, Just to make the 'privileges' issue clear. I used 'phpmyadmin' to give the user 'rfv123@localhost', 'select, update, insert and delete'  rights on databases 'testmysql' and 'rags1'.

Comment: @RyanVincent - ok, I understand now ... I don't know before that it is possible to "overwrite" the "default" db setting ...
Thanks again ... and I will play around ...

Comment: @C3X, You are not overwiting the default db. Once you have a connection to the database - you have access to **everything** that the user you are using can access. :-) There is just a 'default db' that is used if you do not explicitly specify another one.

Comment: @C3X, enjoy and have fun - it is supposed to be fun. I enjoyed playing with this stuff tonight.

Comment: @RyanVincent - I have already changed my code and: IT WORKS!
Your example fit's perfectly ... 
Thanks ;-)

Comment: @C3X, Glad you got it working - 'it works' is always good to hear  :) - accept the answer later if you found it helped. Again - i enjoyed myself and enjoyed helping you.